# Where to save Python Tkinter login data

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Python registration and login code using Tkinter.
But, how and where can I save this recorded data so that a person who created the account on one computer can log on to another?
On google, I only find people saving the data in a local database (.db file on the computer) or in a .txt

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `.db` you can use [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) and working with `.txt`is builtin.
I would recommend hosting your data then so it is not a actual file but on the cloud for stuff like that I would recommend checking out [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/)

Comment: Yes, but that's exactly the problem. If I have a txt or database on the computer with the log data, I won't be able to log into the account on another device. I want a way to save this in something consultable to create a login on any computer in the same account :')

Comment: I would recommend hosting your data then so it is not a actual file but on the cloud for stuff like that I would recommend checking out [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/)

Comment: Sounds good, is there any way I can put the record to be done and saved in MongoDB without having to leave my API Key in the middle of the code so that no one can decrypt and use it?

Comment: Just use some encryption or better yet hash it. @Xpray935

Comment: @Xpray935 just making sure you know what hashing is right? Also if you find this as the correct answer I would appreciate if click the check mark next to rating buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sqlite3 database, but that would not solve your problem.

The database or any other form of data source must be stored on a server that you can access. This can be on the internet or on the local network. (You didn't specify your environment)

you could access this data source by https (don't use http as it is clear text and not a good idea for password requests), connect to an online database or write some kind of socket server that you can connect to and get the needed information.